# How to use Solr stream with pagination

Tags: join, solr, pagination, stream

We have a requirement to fetch data from multiple collections, so we use stream joins to achieve the result. The challenge is, the data is provided to UI where things get done in terms of pages, is there any feature to support that ? like we use start, rows in query handler. Appreciate your ideas and thoughts for the help.

Comment: you can use the rows in the search ...

Comment: something like ....innerJoin(  
 search(abc,q="*:*",fl="abc_ID,*",rows=100, sort="abc_ID desc"),
 search(xyz,q="*:*",fl="xyz_ID,*",rows=100,
                   sort="xyz_ID desc"),
      on="abc_ID=xyz_ID"
   )

Comment: Refer to the sample query used, innerJoin(
    search(collection1, q=*:*, fl="f1, f2 ,f3",sort="f1 asc"),
    search(collection2, q=*:*, fl="f1, f4 ,f5",sort="f1 asc"),
on="f1")

Comment: you can add the rows as shown above...you can refer the documentation....https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/stream-source-reference.html#stream-source-reference

Comment: lets say , Collection1 - 5 records
Collection2 - 20 records (each having 4 mapped records from the collection1, this is for an example, the mapping relational count in collection2 varies as per the key in collection1)
So, if I happen to run above query with 2 rows in search = > is  returning 4 rows in total, in this case I cant move to next counter value of 3 (as we have already fetched 2 records with 0 position) to get the remaning docs.

Comment: I look up for something like below, 
search(innerJoin(
    search(collection1, q=*:*, fl="f1, f2 ,f3", sort="f1 asc"),
    search(collection2, q=*:*, fl="f1, f4 ,f5", sort="f1 asc"),
on="f1"), start=0, rows=10000, sort="f1 asc")

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I read the page https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/stream-source-reference.html#stream-source-reference, the challenge is with implementing pagination. I need to fetch in batches of 10000 records to UI for each call.